# Incorrect Timezone result rectified via column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a MYSQL database that is on a remote shared server.

One of my columns in a table requires to populate automatically with the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP when the record is being populated with other data.

The database uses the SYSTEM time which is "UTC +00:00", but I need this to be "UTC +01:00"

I cannot use "SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+01:00';" as I don't have the priveliges (understandably), and understand there's no way to set a time_zone just at database level (beyond a session instance, this solution needs stick).

Is there a way that I can have my column populate with "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + ADD ONE HOUR", like a calculation?  As I'm looking for a solution at DB level to this.

I'm not db profficient, but appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You will only change time zone,

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_timestamp (
 t1  TIMESTAMP
);

SET time_zone='+00:00';

INSERT INTO test_timestamp 
VALUES('2008-01-01 00:00:01');

SELECT 
    t1
FROM
    test_timestamp;

t1='2008-01-01 00:00:01'

SET time_zone ='+03:00';
 
SELECT t1
FROM test_timestamp;

t1='2008-01-01 03:00:01'
```

Comment: Thanks, but this requires me manually doing that?  I'm looking for a process that is done automatically as outlined above?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the function CONVERT_TZ

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','GMT','MET');
    -> '2004-01-01 13:00:00'
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','+00:00','+10:00');
    -> '2004-01-01 22:00:00'
```

It might be of help to what you need, here's the docs:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Answer (score 0):

you can create a trigger that launched each time you insert in that column

```
 DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_count

AFTER UPDATE ON table_name (time)

  UPDATE table_name
    SET HOUR(column_name) = SEC_TO_TIME((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(HOUR(column_name))+1)*60)
  WHERE time= NEW.time;

END;
$$DELIMITER ;
```